# Is the L-39 Albatros able to go above 40,000 ft in steep flight?

Tags: stall, high-altitude

The [L-39's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aero_L-39_Albatros) service ceiling is 36,100 ft / 11 km but would it be able to easily reach and surpass 40,000 ft MSL if flying a parabola?

Comment: I doubt it. The L-39 is a relatively docile training aircraft that some operators have used for ground attack, but the thrust to *empty* weight ratio is a pitiful 0.49. Put some fuel and a pilot in it and it gets worse. Many refer to it as an aircraft for fighter pilot "wannabe's" with not enough money or experience to fly a more powerful warbird.

Comment: @JuanJimenez Good to know. Thanks.